# Are practical user-created languages suitable for a tag creation?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, meta

I recently created a language, and was wondering (As many others may be) if a user is allowed to create a tag for their language and post a few example questions. The following things should be clarified:

- Should users be able to create tags for their own language?

  - Should they post example questions?
  - Should they use the naming convention used by existing language tags?
  - If they don't have enough rep and/or don't know if they should make the tag, should they post on meta?

I've seen around chat that various users have made their own languages. Should we allow them to create a tag for the language?

<sub>Related: [Do we really need to discuss every new tag?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/do-we-really-need-to-discuss-every-new-tag), [Creating a new language: FreezeFlame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201668/creating-a-new-language-freezeflame)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with Simon's answer, simply because it fails to explicitly address (one of) the most important rule(s) when tagging:

Every question should have a language tag. Not just any language tag, but a tag for the language in which the code is written.

If that's a user-created language, so be it. Get it its own language tag.

When should that tag be created? The moment a question shows up with code written in that language. Don't go around creating language tags pre-emptively. Don't create example questions. If you got code samples, put them in the repository of the language spec. Although, of-course, feel free to write a FizzBuzz to introduce your language to the site.

Comment: FizzBuzz you say? That reminds me, I need to add for loops...

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Or a solution to one of the Eulers, or a 3 doors problem, hangman, it doesn't really matter. Essentially all such questions are introductions to the programming language for the developer with varying degrees of difficulty.

Comment: for loops have been implemented. Now, for a FizzBuzz...

Comment: Fizzbuzz created.  Should I post the equivalent javascript code along with the fizzbuzz?

Comment: `Every question should have a language tag` Not necesarily. Questions that aren't specifically about a piece of code or even a programming language in general cannot logically have a language tag. A typical example of that are questions about general purpuse IDEs.

Comment: @Alejandro This is Code Review. If your question isn't about a specific piece of code in a specific language, I wonder if the question can even be on-topic, as per our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Sure, this answer has a good point. But how would you review this language?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Just like any new language you come across: you learn it a bit before and during review. Of-course, a self-answer to questions with new languages do help to get the tag a bit of momentum.

Comment: @Mast Oh? Will note...

Answer (score 10):

I think about this not as a user-created language but as a [Code Review community project](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5316/31562).

Most importantly: Don't create a tag too soon. In my opinion it's easier to create tags than get rid of them. If your tag would only see a few questions over a few years, then it's not a very useful tag.

#### Should users be able to create tags for their own language?

Possibly, if the language is popular enough.

#### Should they post example questions?

No. You should post questions because you want a review, not because you want to create example questions just so that your language has its own tag.

#### Should they use the naming convention used by existing language tags?

Not entirely sure what naming conventions you are referring to, but sure - why not?

#### If they don't have enough rep and/or don't know if they should make the tag, should they post on meta?

Not necessarily. If you don't have enough reputation and/or don't know if you should create the tag: Then don't create it.

If you have enough reputation and think that there should be a tag, ask in chat and see if others agree. If you then think it should be taken to meta, take it to meta. If you after discussing in chat think that there should be a new tag, then create a new tag.

Follow [these guidelines](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5993/31562) as an indication about whether or not there should be a tag.

Comment: The naming convention I am reffering to is that Javascript is [tag:javascript] Python is [tag:python]... as opposed to [tag:bf-user]

Comment: @FreezePhoenix What would bf-user be? I see 0 questions with that tag.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example. I meant something like `javascript-user-made` or some other way to denote the language was made by a user *in* the name itself.

Comment: @FreezePhoenix Well, you could *possibly* use `custom-language` or something general to indicate that, I don't think `javascript-user-made` would be good as that would also prompt a `python-user-made` and a `java-user-made` and so on. Having one general tag for all home-made languages would be enough, but there is already the [tag:language-design] tag which is related to that (though not exactly what you are looking for).

Comment: @FreezePhoenix I'm also wondering a bit how welcome a question would be if it was of the form "I wrote this code in language XYZ but there's only three people in the world that know this language, and oh - I created this language". How would you review something like that?

Comment: You make a good point - The grammar should be posted at some point, and the language should also explain what it compiles to (if applicable), so that users attempting to review can answer the question.

Comment: In the case that a user wrote the language, I would think that it would unnecessary to post a review, as you would expect they would know what the performance costs of operations are, and what the general recommendations would be. In the case of it being a language that is transpiled, they should also post the transpiled code, so that it is known what it is doing in effect.